# ./configure with multiple cores

Tags: build

Is it possible to let `configure` use multiple cores?

Background: I've compiled a project and `configure` seemed to mainly check prerequisites and set independent options in configuration files. It is possible to inform `make` with the option `-j` that multiple cores shall be used, therefore it is natural to consider other components of a build process as well.